# Make changes without restarting tomcat all over again

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm using `spring mvc` and `spring data jpa` with `eclipse` And it's very annoying that every time i make `ctrl+s` to my java classes my `tomcat` get restarting.
Also for example if i made changes in my `controller` why `tomcat` when he restart it make again connection and create bean of `hibernate` !.

There is not a way to deploy my project without restarting and see the changes made to my java classes ?

Comment: Check Launching option of server.
Window--> Preferences --> Server --> Launching
Check last option "When required, restart server". make it Prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) - it's designed to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: That wasn't stated as a requirement.

Comment: free for personal use though, via my.jrebel.com

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at spring-loaded. Jrebel has more features, but spring-loaded is open source.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded